# Connect iPhone app to remote database server

Tags: mysql, ios, ios6

New to iPhone dev here. Just wondering what's the best way to connect an iPhone app frontend (based on Cocoa touch ) to a php/MySql based backend?

The iPhone application will frequently access and change data stored on our server.

Read about mysql framework and MCPKit framework but these are for cocoa not for cocoa touch.

so can I access mysql based backend without any web service on server side.?

Many thanks

Comment: for security reasons too I wouldn't allow a direct access, the next is the performance

Comment: is this possible or not please help me

Comment: everthing is possible, but for lazyy ppl nothing. How about to do a simple google search?!

Comment: http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/06/02/mysql-and-objective-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a REST Api for your PHP/mySQL. Something like this

https://github.com/gilbitron/Arrest-MySQL

Then on the iOS side of things, you can use something like AFNetworking, to make requests to your server.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking